# Getting data from android device and plot in browser

Tags: android, browser, plot, adb

I am trying to get data from app running on android device and plot it in a browser running on PC.

I considered below methods

**Method 1**

1. Write data from android app to cirular files[ file1.txt -> file2.txt -> file3.txt -> file1.txt ] at regular intervals, in my case 1 sec.
2. Pull the files using adb in circular order.
3. Again use the same circular order in reading files in browser using XMLHttpRequest and plot using some javascript.

Here I am facing some error while reading the file using XMLHttpRequest, there may be a  issue of synchronisation -> reading and writing of the files.

I think this is very **naive** approach.

**Method 2**

I considered one more option of using USB tethering to establish a TCP connection between device and PC and get data from the APP from client-socket running on PC. ( This method sounds better than writing data into files in the device and pulling files using adb ).

Still unable to find  a way to send the data received from device to browser for plotting.

**Constraints**

I am not allowed to use any kind of webserver on the device side.

Any method I think of has some kind of ping-pong/circular approach somewhere in the process, which I think is not a good option.

I know this sounds like pretty simple problem to many of you.

It will be of great help, if anybody gives some elegant approach.

Comment: care to explain why the "plotting" application has to be a browser?

Comment: What we are planning is like this.  To get the log we should not use the same ip as the APP, cos the bandwidth used to generate log info shouldn't consume APP's bandwidth. Idea is send device data to PC1, and access that data from any other PC2( can be any where ), which has just net and browser, no additional tools, a kind of remote debugging just by plots.

Comment: Since your device is going to be connected to PC and available via `ADB` why not just let your android app write the data into the log and let another app process the `adb logcat` output on the PC side and then share it over the net by whatever means you want?

Comment: Hi Alex. The process of getting data using adb logcat (i believe, is same as getting the data using tcp connection over usb which is my second method) and keep on appending the data to some file or some memory. Your suggestion of reading that file or that memory on pc with another process, where i am stuck at. Data wont be coming continuously, so when reading data from another app on pc( which is very fast) at some point gets file end. Here is where I don't know how to proceed further in the other app which is reading the data for processing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could able to find answer in some form.

1. Open TCP/UDP connection from the app running on Device to PC to which it is connected (using USB) and send data.
2. a) If data has to be processed, process that data in another application and send the processed data to node.js running on PC
   b) If there is no processing required directly send data from Device to node.js
3. Open websocket in node.js and send that data to browser running on another PC.